android - autocomplete raw keyboard input from onKey (custom widgets, not using Android provided widgets)
I'm using my own widgets with onKey() handlers extending View.OnKeyListener. But when typing text, I want to offer the user the ability to select suggestions from the candidates view.
After a lot of reading, it seems I must register my own InputMethodService? So I modified my AndroidManifest.xml like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="darkfi.darkwallet"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="0.1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="31" android:minSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"></uses-feature>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />, 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application 
            android:hasCode="true" android:label="DarkWallet"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" >
        
    <service
        android:name="autofill.AutofillService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.view.im" android:resource="@xml/method" />
    </service>
        <activity 
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="DarkWallet"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" 
                android:exported="true"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="darkwallet" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

Then I also put this in res/xml/method.xml:
<input-method xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:supportsInlineSuggestions="true">
</input-method>

I did not change anything in my MainActivity and I create this file in java/autofill/AutofillService.java:
package autofill;

import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.inline.InlinePresentationSpec;
import android.view.inputmethod.InlineSuggestion;
import android.view.inputmethod.InlineSuggestionsRequest;
import android.view.inputmethod.InlineSuggestionsResponse;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AutofillService extends InputMethodService {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("darkfi", "inline onCreate() called");
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        Log.d("darkfi", "onCreateInputView");
        return super.onCreateInputView();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d("darkfi", "inline onKeyDown");
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}

However when I run the app, then show the keyboard and type, absolutely nothing shows up in the log. It's like my InputMethodService isn't even created.
If there is a simpler way to do what I'm trying to achieve, then please suggest it.
What am I missing?

ok turns out I was going about this wrong. For more info see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79234201/android-custom-input-connection-not-catching-key-events-from-the-soft-keyboard-i
