android custom input connection not catching key events from the soft keyboard IME
I am implementing my own text edit widgets in Android, and now wanted to implement the spellcheck autocorrect. I managed to figure out that I must extend BaseInputConnection, and now am able to get suggestions from the soft keyboard IME.
However my view no longer is able to catch key down events from View.OnKeyListener enabled by setOnKeyListener(). I tried then using the sendKeyEvent() method in BaseInputConnection but that does not give me the intermediate chars either.
I'm trying to get the intermediate text (typically what is shown with an underline) before commitText() is called in BaseInputConnection. I think the best way is just by intercepting sendKeyEvent() but it isn't being called.
It is called for buttons that aren't handled by the autocorrect suggestions like pressing the power button, but not for the actual keyboard.
Here's my code:
package com.example.simple;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputContentInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.CompletionInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Window;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.Editable;

class CustomInputConnection extends BaseInputConnection {

    public CustomInputConnection(View view, boolean fullEditor) {
        super(view, fullEditor);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        Log.i("darkfi", "got key event");
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            char keyChar = (char)event.getUnicodeChar();
            Log.i("darkfi", "key event: " + keyChar);
        }
        return super.sendKeyEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean commitText(CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition) {
        Log.i("darkfi", String.format("commitText(%s, %d)", text.toString(), newCursorPosition));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setSelection(int start, int end) {
        Log.i("darkfi", "setSelection");
        return true;
    }
}

class CustomView
    extends
        View
    implements
        View.OnTouchListener {

    private InputMethodManager imm;

    public CustomView(Context context, InputMethodManager imm){
        super(context);

        this.imm = imm;

        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        requestFocus();
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("darkfi", "onTouch() v1");
        imm.showSoftInput(this, 0);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;
        outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE;
        // fullEditor is false, but we might set this to true for enabling
        // text selection, and copy/paste. Lets see.
        return new CustomInputConnection(this, true);
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private CustomView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("darkfi", "onCreate()");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        //imm.showSoftInput(view, 0);
        //imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 1);

        view = new CustomView(this, imm);
        setContentView(view);
    }
}

Any ideas what's wrong?

OK you must override this method:
    @Override
    public boolean endBatchEdit() {
        String curr = getTextBeforeCursor(100, 0).toString();
        Log.i("darkfi", "endBatchEdit: " + curr);
        return super.endBatchEdit();
    }

